# Uneven background correction using Top hats

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I am trying to correct uneven background illumination in the text document using Morphological top-hat operation.
[image]

After applying Top hat, result  I get is worse for analysis than the original image.

```
img=rgb2gray(imread("test2.png"));
se=strel("square",100);
imshow(imtophat(img,se));
```

[image]
 Could you please advice what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top hat filter works for light text on a black background. You can either invert the image (`imcomplement`) before applying the top hat, or use `imbothat` instead.

In either case, the output is identical: light text on a black background. You can invert the image after the operation to get dark text on a white background.